# Media 2.x requires File entity 2.x - Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I updated the media module and when I run `update.php` file, I get the following error:

> "Media 2.x requires File entity 2.x. Please download the correct version and make sure you have deleted the file_entity folder inside the media module directory."

Could you please let me know how to update the file entity module?

Comment: It seems you are updating Media module from 1.x to 2.x version. If yes, then you should look at this guide https://www.drupal.org/node/2082037.

Comment: I am changing 1.6 to 2.3 version. After updating media module i downloaded file entity module and uploaded manually in to media folder from backend. After that when i try to run update.php its not working still same error message is showing

Comment: Basically, the file_entity module earlier comes within the media module in older version i.e. inside "sites/all/modules/media" folder and you need to remove that one first and then install the new file_entity module as a standalone inside the "sites/all/modules/ directory. Then when you will run the update.php, it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much.Its working Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the File entity module and ran update.php. It is working fine.

The old version of media module includes file entity module but for newer versions, we have to install it separately.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18473383)

Comment: Actually, the answer was in comments as there is no option to accept there I  added separately.

Comment: In that case, please provide a complete answer describing how you solved the problem and accept it. You can accept your own answer.